#    btnAdd click event opens two window after record added

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

i m opening window(search.aspx)using below code.
 i hav add button in search.aspx 
when i insert record from btnAdd click event then it opens another window. 
after inserting record i have to close that window. How can i do that.

```
       //calling Search.aspx on button click of abc.aspx
      if (window.showModalDialog) {
        window.showModalDialog("Search.aspx","name",
        "dialogWidth:255px;dialogHeight:250px");
        }
        //Search.aspx code behind
        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          //Insert query for adding record
        }

//Search.aspx code
$(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("input[id$='btnAdd']").live('click', function (e)
            {
                if ($(".csstablelisttdselected").length == 0)
                {
                    alert("Select patient to fixed appointment.");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    hidPID.value = $('table td.csstablelisttdselected:first').text();                   
                }
            });
        });

    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" Width="110px" CssClass="cssbutton" runat="server" Text="Add"
                    OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

Comment: Where are you calling your `window.showModalDialog` code on search.aspx load or on some other page ??

Comment: On another page button click i m calling window.showModalDialog

Comment: And this button is a simple HTML input button or you are posting the page to the server and injecting this script to your page manually ??

Comment: Are you closing your popup window after save ? If not then try to close with `window.close()` it I guess that would solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply in the modal window put this to the `<HEAD>`

```
<BASE target="_self">
```